# Error Code 1064 using window functions in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am currently having problems using window functions in MySql, i.e. the following code:

```
SELECT 
    A, 
    B, 
    LAG(A,1) OVER(ORDER BY B) AS NextA
FROM 
   foo;
```

Fails with:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM  foo' at line 6

Comment: If you are not on version 8 or above window functions are not available.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running ?